# Stop autocomplete in jqGrid

Tags: autocomplete, passwords, free-jqgrid

I'm using the free version of jqGrid 5.2.0. My problem is that I have grid managing users. I use form editing to add users but everytime I bring up the form the username and password field is autocompleted with the currently logged in users details. I've tried changing the names of the fields but it still happens. I've also tried adding autocomplete=false to the grid definition.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you use currently *commercial* [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which is not free. See the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I develop *alternative* fork under the name [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which can be used really completely free of charge under MIT and GPL v2 licenses.

About your question. You can set `autocomplete="off"` attribute on the input fields of the username and the password field. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) for details. To set the `autocomplete` one can use `editoptions` property of `colModel`. There are some well-known predefined properties like `dataInit`, `dataUrl` and so on. All other properties of `editoptions` will be interpreted as *attribute*, which need be set. Thus you need just use

```js
editoptions: { autocomplete: "off" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are actually using the free version 4.14.0. The version number I gave was from the paid version we tried but we ditched that as the support was non existant. I'll try your suggestion. Many thanks for all your hardwork on jqgrid.

Comment: @SimonRyan: You are welcome! Let me know about the result of your tests. By the way, the current version of free jqGrid is 4.14.1.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in Chrome. Give me this markup...
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="UserName" name="UserName" role="textbox" class="FormElement form-control">
but the autocomplete still works.

Comment: @SimonRyan: It's difficult to solve any problem if you don't provide the demo and the test case, which describe the problem. In any way the problem consist of two parts: 1) one should know, which changes on HTML should be done or which JavaScript code should be executed. 2) How to do this (the step 1) in jqGrid Add/Edit form. My main answer: if you need set attribute of field of Edit form - add attribute in `editoptions`. If you need execute JavaScript code - use `dataInit` of `editoptions`. What exactly solves your problem (step 1) is not possible without the demo and reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop autocomplete for form editing when using Chrome the following works...

```
editoptions: { autocomplete: "new-password" }
```